# Set height of event with no end

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In my `agendaDay` view I some times need to display events that do not have an end time:

```
$(".agenda").fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: "Start day",
            start: '2017-04-19T09:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: "Do some work",
            start: '2017-04-19T09:05:00',
            end: '2017-04-19T17:00:00'
        }
    ]
});
```

Such events get rendered as if they lasted two hours:

[image: Agenda View]

Is there a way to control that or an alternative feature I should be using?

Docs for v1 mention [the exact property I need](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/agenda/defaultEventMinutes/):

> `defaultEventMinutes` 1.4
>
> Determines the length (in minutes) an event appears to be when it has
>   an unspecified end date.
>
> ```
> Integer, default: 120
> ```
>
> By default, if an Event Object as no end, it will appear to be 2
>   hours.

... but the property is apparently not available on 3.3.1 :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the v2 & 3 API it's been split in two properties, so you can set different values to *all day* events and *timed* ones:

- [defaultAllDayEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/)
- [defaultTimedEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/)

Also, the new properties expect a string with a time (`"00:45:00"`) rather than seconds (<del>`2700`</del>).